# SSRS grouping values in a range

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, range, grouping

I am trying to build a frequency histogram of grouped data, where my initial values along the x-axis are floating point numbers. For instance, I have the monetary value for each item in my database and I want to count the number of items where the value is between 0 to 49, then 50 - 99, then 100 to 149, and so forth.

How can I group my data in SSRS as described above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually have the SSRS tool with me but i remember that you can set your default grouping by going to `CustomAttribute`  category which you will find it in properties window for the chart.In that category you have a property  called `HistogramSegmentIntervalWidth` .You can set that value to 50

MSDN Doc:- [HistogramSegmentIntervalWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220610%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I keep getting one large column from $0 to $50... Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you have lot of data in that interval

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had to select the monetary value in the series rather than the count, because SSRS does all the work for you. Thanks!